# R - Calculate distance between two points along a polyline

Tags: r, distance, polyline

In R - I have imported a polyline shapefile that is not straight (represents a winding interstate highway) into the environment.  I have read a .csv file that contains points (latitude/longitude in decimal degrees) into the environment.  All of those points lie along the polyline.

If I take two random points I can calculate the "as the crow flies" distance between them using great circle distance calculation.  But what is needed is distance traveled along the polyline. See reference image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhorb.png

Is anyone aware of an R package that can calculate the distance between two lat/lon points along a polyline?

Comment: Your question is too broad.  *Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.*

Comment: I have completely re-written my question.

Answer (score 1):

Package `PBSmapping` has a `calcLength` function which directly calculates the length of a polyline or polygon (in what it terms a `PolySet`). The package can import ESRI shapefiles as well, if your shapefile is in that format.

Example of a simple polyline:

```
line = read.table(text = "X, Y, POS, PID
37.772, -122.214, 1, 1
21.291, -157.821, 2, 1
-18.142, 178.431, 3, 1
-27.467, 153.027, 4, 1", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

library(PBSmapping)
pline = as.PolySet(line, projection = 1)

calcLength(pline)
  PID   length
1   1 404.8539 

plotLines(pline)
```

[image]