# Calculate distance between two consecutive points along a line from OSM

Tags: r, gis, distance, shapefile, rgdal

I have **shapefile** with road trafic from OSM and **dataframe** with GPS coordinates. I want to calculate road network distances between each two consecutive GPS points from dataframe along a line.

I found this solution: [How to calculate geographic distance between two points along a line in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49760063/how-to-calculate-geographic-distance-between-two-points-along-a-line-in-r)

Shapefile from OSM is there: https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/slovakia-latest-free.shp.zip

**My code:**

```
library("rgdal")
library("rgeos")

#lines from osm
lines <- readOGR(dsn="slovakia-latest-free.shp",layer="gis_osm_roads_free_1")
route <- spTransform(lines, CRS("+init=epsg:32634"))

#my gps points
m <- data.frame(LON=c(18.86365, 18.86357, 18.86355, 18.86301, 18.86286),
              LAT=c(49.18286,49.18095,49.17907,49.17754,49.17715),
              OSM_ID=c("33544857","33544857","33544851","843079370","33544922"))

wgs84 <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
p = SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=m[,1:2], proj4string = wgs84, data=m)
p = spTransform(p,CRS("+init=epsg:32634"))

#count dist along a line
diff(gProject(route, p))

l <- subset(route, osm_id %in% c(33544857,33544851,843079370,33544922))
plot(l, axes=TRUE,col="orange")  
plot(p, add=TRUE)
```

**Result**

```
[1]  2.130847e+02 -1.258070e+03  1.449036e+08 -1.449011e+08
```

**Problem**

The problem is that the gProject function returns the correct result only when both GPS points lie on the same line (in this case on the same OSM edge). In my data, only the first two points lie on the same line, so only the first result is correct, the others are wrong and weird. So I'd like to ask if there's a way to do it correctly, maybe connecting the lines would help.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The `readOGR()` doesn't work for me, so is difficult to figure out what is wrong with the code. Can you use something like this to calculate distance between two lat/long pairs? https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for response, you need to download data first from::https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/slovakia-latest-free.shp.zip

Comment: I need to calculate the distance along the line. gProject function does this and I think my solution is good, but my problem is that not all of my consecutive GPS points are on the same line. So I'm looking for a solution to solve this problem, e.g. whether it is possible to combine all lines into one line. Thanks